# Accelerometer Bias estimation with kalman filter

Tags: matlab, filters, estimation, kalman-filters

I have to estimate biases of a 3-axes accelerometer by modyfying an existent kalman filter mounted on a drone. The biases are assumed constant.
The filter has 9 states: position (xyz), velocity (xyz) and acceleration (xyz) in navigation frame and no inputs.
Measurements are taken from GPS, IMU and baro.
An ahrs filter takes gyro, Imu e mag measurements to estimate roll,pitch and yaw.
To include Bias in the state Vector, I considered the measurement of accelerometer as :
Acc = acc_ned + Cbn * Bias;
The rotation Matrix from navigation to body frame Is needed since my Bias Is in body frame.
With this equation I wrote the relative modified matrices A and C and applied the Linear discrete-time kalman filter. The estimated Bias is substracted in feedback to the accelerometer measurement entering the ahrs filter.
I can't maKe this loop to work; my biases don't converge to constant values.
I'm trying simulations on MATLAB/simulink.
Has anyone ever tried to estimate accelerometer's biases with kalman filter? Has anyone any ideas?
Thank you in adavnce

Comment: I'm not sure if you can separate out the position and AHRS measurements in this manner.  If you can, I doubt that it can be done without knowing exactly what the AHRS is doing (and I don't mean buzzwords -- I mean the underlying math).  Basically, the AHRS is using the accelerometer reading to determine orientation, while your Kalman filter is using the orientation to determine the accelerometer reading.  This is forming a feedback loop.  Without taking the loop characteristics into account (by understanding the AHRS *exactly*), you may be out of luck.

Comment: The one time I did something like this, there was one Kalman filter that calculated orientation, position, velocity, and gyro and accelerometer biases.  I don't think you can correctly account for the interplay between all these factors without having one big Kalman filter at work.